# What is the most common way to end a phone call?

Tags: conversación-telefónica

Similar to [my other question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/815/what-is-the-most-common-way-to-answer-the-phone), what is the most universal way of ending a phone call in Spanish (the last thing you'd say after ending your conversation before hanging up)? In English, we'd say things like:

- Ok, bye.
- See ya.
- Great, talk to you later.

What options are there in Spanish?

Comment: This sounds like a list question @jrdioko...

Comment: Don't take SE's hatred for "list questions" too literally. If you investigate why they hate them you'll see what they really hate are "open ended lists" and this may (or not) be a very small list. At least the opposite question of how to begin a phone call in Spanish would be a very short and definite list.

Comment: @Joze: Yeah, I thought about that, but I intentionally try to make these as specific as possible ("What is the most common way..." as opposed to "What are all the possible ways...").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some I can think of:

- Chao (Bye - *Chau* is most common in Argentina, as user1074377 pointed out. Chao, I believe, is the most universal one.)
- Bye, cuídate (Bye, take care)
- Bueno, saludos (Ok, regards).

If talking to a very good friend, I'd say:

- Bueno, un abrazo (Ok, hugs)

Answer (score 3):

In Argentina I most commonly heard people ending a phone call with **'Chau'**
Usually in English we repeat goodbye a few times before we end a call like, **'Ok then, ok bye, ok see you'**
I heard the same sort of thing in Argentina, **'Bueno chau, besos, ok dale, chau chau'** etc.

Answer (score 2):

*Supplemental answer*

If it's been a chatty, longish interaction, you need to indicate that you're ready to wrap things up, as preparation for saying good-bye.  Here are some ways to do that:

- Bueno, pues, (name of person), fue un placer.  Luego hablamos, ¿eh?  (response) Saludos a todos.